# How to check button is pressed or not in while loop in java?

Tags: java, swing, loops, java-native-interface

I've a native function called `get`, I'm checking the returned value in while loop by this function. If this returned value is 1, I continue to get different returned value. However, as you predict it cause infinite loop in this way. So that, I also want to check the stop button is pressed to break infinite while loop. How can I do that?

**My Native Function**

```
int rValue = get();  // I get returned value here from native get() function

while(rValue == 1)
{
   rValue = get();  // I'm trying to get different returned value here
   if(stopButton.getModel().isPressed() == true) // I tried something like this but didn't work
        break;
}

if(rValue == -1)
{
  // do something
}
```

Comment: *"How to check button is pressed or not in while loop in java?
"* - generally you don't.  You use an `ActionListener` which is notified when the button is pressed and you then perform any required operations

Comment: ActionListener also doesn't work in while loop

Comment: No, this is what I mean, you don't need the loop, this is bad idea in an event driven environment and indicates that you still have a linear/procedural mentality.  Instead, you relay on, things like, an observer pattern, which is used to notify when some state changes, to which you can then respond to it.

Comment: This while loop in start button, so I mean, I always use ActionListener to start get() function

Comment: Your question makes no sense and lacks context

Comment: I assume it didn't work because your loop runs on the Main thread. It's OK to run your *almost infinite* loop on a background thread. But it may be even better to use an [Executor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Action Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html) to achieve this

Something like this,

```
stopButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        System.out.println("Stop Button Clicked");
    }
});
```